Condicionales Html y PHP en Laravel
Buen día a todos, soy principiante con laravel y quería de su ayuda, tengo problemas con una condición, el if envía un valor de disponibilidad para que presente un valor x y en el caso de ser 0 arroje un mensaje: (sin disponibilidad).
<div class="clear-both"></div>
{% if disponibilidad %}
<div class="bg-orange text-white programdates text-left p-4 my-4">
    <p class="font-subtitle mb-4 text-white">LUGARES DISPONIBLES:{{ disponibilidad }}</p>
</div> 
<div class="clear-both"></div>
{% endif %}

